# Unity 2D - How to disable collision between some layers, but not others, yet still detect collision between all layers

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I have 3 colliders with different layers. How do I make collider A collide with collider B and not with collider C, but still detect the collision between collider C, like a trigger.

I tried disabling collision between collider A and C in the collision matrix, but then I couldn't detect the collision between those two colliders.

Comment: you can turn it on per collider, but its a lot of work

Comment: Just to clarify: You want that `A` collides with `B`, `B` collides with `C` but between `A` and `C` it should behave like a trigger, right? One way I can imagine that is having an additional collider layer `D` which basically is a clone of the collider `C` and then setup: `C` not trigger - collides with `B` but not `A`; `D` is trigger - collides with `A`. it's quite a "dumb" approach but works ^^

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. My solution is to use **Tags** instead of **Layers**. Go to **Project Settings** -> **Physics 2D**, and roll down to the bottom.
[image]

In my project, I don't want **Enemy** to collide with **CanBeClimbed** objects, and **Enemy** collide with each other so I untagged it. Done.